# Is there a way to convert TeX to Markdown with SVGs for equations and PGF/TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, svg, markdown, mathjax

I'm building a static blog with Jekyll and I've got some TeX documents which I'd like to convert to Markdown. I tried using `pandoc` but most of the inline equations (especially those with `aligned` environments) fail to render, and with theorem environments, there are unwanted texts like "::: remark".

Is there a way to convert all the equations and PGF/TikZ plots to SVG files and embed them in the Markdown so that the final web page looks identical to the PDF compiled by `pdflatex`? Of course, I don't mean identical pixel by pixel, I just want all the equations and plots rendered correctly and the layout to be the same. Also, if there's a way to render the equations correctly just using MathJax that's even more ideal.

Comment: you can use mathjax and just let the math copy through, see math stackexchange in this network,or github flavoured markdown for examples that do this

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is exactly the problem, when I use pandoc to convert, it uses MathJax and inline equations with environment `aligned` failed to render